# How to use Telerik GridHyperLinkColumn to open folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Very quickly, I have a Telerik RadGrid that allows users to upload files to a specific shared server folder location when in edit mode. The users would like a way to select a button on the grid and open the specific folder to show all attachments for that unique row. I am able to successfully use an asp hyperlink control on the popup editing form to show them all attachments within the folder.

I tried adding a GridHyperlinkColumn and a GridTemplateColumn on the RadGrid itself and set the navigation URL to what I did in the code behind, but I am getting a 404 ERROR. Is this relating to how I am writing the folder address?

**OPTION 1**

```
<Telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="hyperlink">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypDirLink" runat="server" Target="_self"
      NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("\\server-name\data$\CADLog\{0}, Eval("CAD_ID")) %>'>
      <img src="../Images/Files-icon.png" alt="Open Folder" />
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</Telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**OPTION 2**

```
<Telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="CAD_ID" UniqueName="hyperLinkColumn"
  DataNavigateUrlFields="CAD_ID" ImageUrl="~/Images/Files-icon.png" Target="_self"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~//server-name/data$/CADLog/{0}" />
```

**OPTION 3**

I have tried a few different ways of formatting the server folder location such as:

```
~\\server-name\data$\CADLog\{0}
.\\server-name\data$\CADLog\{0}
~//server-name/data$/CADLog/{0}
.//server-name/data$/CADLog/{0}
\\server-name\data$\CADLog\{0} <-- this is the URL I get when I copy from Windows Explorer
//server-name/data$/CADLog/{0}
```

I have double, triple, quadruple checked that this file does exist on the server and that I have the correct permissions setup on this shared server location. Whenever I click on the link it tries to open the navigation URL within the browser instead of opening Windows Explorer.

I have a ticket open with Telerik Support to try and resolve this, but they do not know what I am trying to do with the above control and have said the controls should be working if it is modeled the same.

Answer (score 0):

To open a folder location on the shared server, I only needed to add one thing to the GridHyperLinkColumn:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="File://server-name/data$/CADLog/{0}"
```

This worked perfectly for me and works on the server.